# If I'm learning PL/SQL, is there no need for MySQL?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am still new to programming but if I start with PL/SQL does it mean I don't have to learn MySQL as well?

Comment: Did you read the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) of the tags you used? What has MySql got to do with *"Oracle Corporation's procedural language extension for SQL"*? In any case, opinions about what is required to learn is totally subjective and off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two different things :

**PL/SQL** is a database language used with Oracle Database.

Whereas **MySQL** is a database itself that uses SQL language.

Comment: Humble apologies. But do I have to learn a database also with pl/SQL or is within its capability to manipulate, create and influence as a programming language and learning the database back-end?

It doesn't just have to be just MySql. Excuse me, but would it be lucrative at this point to just learn pl/SQL.

Comment: @dwaynesauls: PL/SQL is specific to the Oracle database products. So, if you wish to learn Oracle database technology then by all means learn PL/SQL. However, Oracle technology is generally very expensive, so by learning this you are putting yourself in a specific market sector (e.g. banks and large insurance companies). MySQL is free and open-source, and targets a different market segment. Choose the one that you believe will get you employment in your area.

Comment: If you are going to learn a database language, you will have to learn how works a database. MySQL uses SQL language so it is a good idea to take a loot at it.

Answer (score 2):

Language PL/SQL isn't used for MySQL database so you don't need to know it